# NumPy: generalize one-hot encoding to k-hot encoding

Tags: numpy

I'm using this code to one-hot encode values:

```
idxs = np.array([1, 3, 2])
vals = np.zeros((idxs.size, idxs.max()+1))
vals[np.arange(idxs.size), idxs] = 1
```

But I would like to generalize it to k-hot encoding (where shape of `vals` would be same, but each row can contain k ones).

Unfortunatelly, I can't figure out how to index multiple cols from each row. I tried `vals[0:2, [[0, 1], [3]]` to select first and second column from first row and third column from second row, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [*advanced-indexing*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing).

> to select first and second column from first row and third column from second row

You just need to pass the respective rows and columns in separate iterables (tuple, list):

```
In [9]: a
Out[9]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

In [10]: a[[0, 0, 1],[0, 1, 3]]
Out[10]: array([0, 1, 8])
```

Comment: One last question – does NumPy has any function, which turns `[[1, 3], [2], [0, 2]]` into `[0, 0, 1, 2, 2]`?

Comment: @user1518183 No. Whats the logic behind that?

Comment: Right, it does not make any sense.